# Mod Rewrite Rule not matching certain words

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm no expert in mod_rewrite at all and I'm trying to add a condition to the rule below to:

1. match which is not equal to 'share'
2. not match anything with a dot in it

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://domain.com/directory/index.php?key=$1 [L]`

`http://domain.com/directory/share` will not be matched (share)

`http://domain.com/directory/foo.php` will not be matched (contains a dot)

`http://domain.com/directory/abcde` will be matched

`http://domain.com/directory/abcde-4` will be matched

All ULRs will not have a trailing slash

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't match anything with a dot by adding `.` to the negated character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]*)$ <snip>
```

Don't match an ending `/share`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*/share)$ <snip>
```

Combine them to not-match either using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
RewriteRule ^([^./])*(?!/share)$ <snip>
```

Comment: Or do I just make three rules?

`RewriteRule ^([^./]*(?!share))$ http://domain.com/directory/index.php?key=$1 [L]`

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*/share)$ http://domain.com/directory/index.php?key=$1 [L]`

`RewriteRule ^([^./]*(?!share))$ http://domain.com/directory/index.php?key=$1 [L]`

Comment: I see, it's kind of working but the `key` is always `share` - regardless of what the matched characters are. The dynamic url should be http://domain.com/directory/index.php?key=abcde-3 and not http://domain.com/directory/index.php?key=share

Comment: Try moving the parens: `^([^./])*(?!/share)$` (sorry, it's just a guess, but I've been awake for ~22 hours)